# Вывести все значения атрибута на отдельной странице Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Возникла вот такая задача. В интернет магазине, сделанном на Wordpress с использованием Woocommerce, у каждого товара есть атрибут Бренд (pa_brand). По задумке дизайнера должна быть страница, где все эти бренды выведены на отдельной странице. Так вот вопрос, возможно ли это технически реализовать и как это сделать?

Как вывести товары на страницу, по этим атрибутам, я знаю, а вот как вывести ВСЕ значения этого атрибута, не могу разобраться.

Пробовал вот так, но выдает ошибку: Warning: Attempt to read property "id" on null in brand-page.php on line 13

Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, bool given in brand-page.php on line 14

```
<?php
 
    global $product;
 
    $brand_values = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_brand');
    foreach ( $brand_values as $brand_value ) {
          echo $brand_value->name;
    }
?>
```

Буду очень признателен за помощь. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Немного переделал код и все получилось

```
<?php    global $product;
                $terms=get_terms('pa_brand'); //тут вместо brand нужно вставить Ярлык вашего Атрибута, то есть pa_ярлык
                foreach ($terms as $each_term) {
                echo '<h2>'.$each_term->name.'</h2>';
                } 
            ?>
```